# Promisificar una forma: ¿Cómo acceder la acción de lectura?

Tags: javascript, formularios, promesas

Quiero llamar una función y que esta muestre una forma y retorne lo leído.

El problema es que no veo cómo enlazar la función de lectura (Que podría usar de callback) de modo que pueda asignarla en la promesa

Para aclarar:

Puedo asignar una función cualquiera al "submit" o a un botón cualquiera para procesar la forma.

Mi problema es cómo enlazar esa función con una promesa para poder esperar el resultado de la lectura

Comment: En qué sentido esperarla? El click gatilla un handler, dentro de ese handler Puedes gatillar la promesa, mostrar un "loading" y retornar false. La promesa al resolver oculta el loading y muestra el resultado

Answer (score 1):

```js
function funcionALigar(src){

     let img = new Image();
     return new Promise((res, rej)=>{

         img.onload = ()=>{
              return res(img);
         }
   
         img.onerror = (e)=>{
              return rej(e);
         }

         img.src = src;

     });
}

const imgSrc = "https://www.sanborns.com.mx/imagenes-sanborns-ii/1200/630509245680_2.jpg";
const promiseParaCargarImagen = new Promise((res, rej)=>{
     
    return funcionALigar(imgSrc).then(data =>{

        return res(data);

    }).catch(e =>{

        return rej(e);

    });

});

promiseParaCargarImagen.then(data =>{

     document.createElement("img");
     document.body.appendChild(data);

}).catch(e =>{

     console.error(e);

});
```

Mas o menos ese es un ejemplo de como podrías ligar una promise con otra función, en este caso lo que hacemos es intentar realizar la carga de una imagen, normalmente las promises se usan para la carga de datos asincronos o que puedan tardar, como imagenes, video o audio, por lo que me parecio un buen ejemplo, entonces, pongamos de ejemplo esta parte:

```
 //Creamos la imagen pero no le ponemos ruta, muy importante
 let img = new Image();
 /*
  Se retorna la promesa entera ya que la necesitaremos para luego ejecutarla
  en la promise que vamos a ligar con esta función, el parametro res es un callback automatico de las promises, lo debes ejecutar en caso de que no haya errores, por el contrario el parametro rej, es para lo contrario, y en ambos casos debes retornar el resultado de estas operaciones
 */
 return new Promise((res, rej)=>{

     /*
       Asignamos primero los eventos a la imagen antes de darle una ruta
       Si lo hacemos alrevez nuestra promesa se quedaria en estado "pending"
     */
     img.onload = ()=>{

          /*
           En caso de exito de carga retornamos la ejecución del callback res
           pasandole como parametro la imagen, esto exportara el valor a la 
           promise (le dira que debe devolve en caso de exito).
          */
          return res(img);
     }

     img.onerror = (e)=>{

          //En caso de error simplemente ejecutamos el callback rej con el parametro e, en este caso la e nos la proporciona el metodo onerror.
          return rej(e);
     }

     /*
      Por ultimo habiendole añadido todos los eventos necesarios a la imagen
      ahora si le damos una ruta.
     */
     img.src = src;

 });
```

Ya teniendo nuestra función que retorna la promesa que hace algo en especifico (la promesa para una operación especifica que en este caso es cargar una imagen) lista, entonces procedemos a declarar nuestra ruta:

```
const imgSrc = "https://www.sanborns.com.mx/imagenes-sanborns-ii/1200/630509245680_2.jpg";
```

Ahora procedemos a crear nuestra "Promesa general", la cúal es directamente una promise, no una función, realmente esta parte no se si es del todo necesaria, ya que la función funcionALigar como tal retorna una promise, pero si quieres encadenar una promise con otra promise esta es una manera de hacerlo:

```
const promiseParaCargarImagen = new Promise((res, rej)=>{

    /*
      retornamos la promise entera de la función funcionALigar con el
      parametro imgSrc, así cuando termine de ejecutarse nos dara la
      promise fallida o resuelta pero ya trayendonos la imagen.
    */
    return funcionALigar(imgSrc).then(data =>{

        //En caso de exito la promise ahora almacena la imagen.
        return res(data);

    }).catch(e =>{

        //En caso de fallo la promise almacena un mensaje de error.
        return rej(e);

    });

});
```

Ahora que ya tenemos la promesa general y la especifica, podemos ejecutar la general para que esta nos ejecute la especifica y nos traiga ya sea una imagen o un error, y para capturar bien ambos resultados y poder acceder a estos datos necesitamos como siempre un then y un catch:

```
promiseParaCargarImagen.then(data =>{

     //En caso de exito creamos un elemento imagen y lo metemos al final del body
     document.createElement("img");
     document.body.appendChild(data);

}).catch(e =>{

     //En caso de error hacemos log del error en la consola.
     console.error(e);

});
```

Con esto ya se tiene entonces una forma segura de trabajar con promises para la carga de imagenes. Este sería mi ejemplo.

Comment: Esta es una solución mas bien general, dependiendo de lo que requieras especificamente ya que no te he entendido con lo de cargar una forma, te recomiendo que busques un evento oyente ligado a esa acción entonces lo unico que debes hacer es usar ese evento oyente en la promise dependiendo de lo que necesites, un evento de tipo click, animation, drag, etc, hay varios, si por ejemplo necesitas mostrar la carga de un archivo haces algo parecido a lo que hice con mi imagen pero antes de que la promesa se ejecute debes mostrar un loader o algo y cuando se resuelva o se rechaze la promesa detenerlo.